# Passing char* to QString

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am working on a module in which GUI and back-end interact by message passing.
I initialised a char* as nullptr. GUI takes a QStringList which is tokenized. I cannot do the changes in the tokenized list. I receive a "(null)" in the list. Now I feel like by comparing to "(null)" is not the way to go. Is there any initialisation for char* which would be taken as an empty string by QString?

Comment: Why not pass an empty string, i.e. `""`? Or just a default-constructed `QString` object (which will be an empty string).

Answer (score 3):

Use an empty string when constructing a `QString` when the pointer is `NULL`.

```
QString obj = (ptr == nullptr? QString("") : QString(ptr));
```

And then use `obj`.

Comment: It takes a QStringList which is tokenized. I cannot do the changes in the tokenized list. I receive a "(null)" in the list. Now I feel like by comparing to "(null)" is not the way to go. Is there any initialisation for char* which would be taken as an empty string by QString?

Comment: @ArchitJ, that's a very different question. I think you should enhance your post with new information about what your code does and where it runs into the NULL pointer problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what you want but if i am not mistaken :

```
char *c = nullptr;
QString str(c);

str.isEmpty(); // return true
```